# What does const after function header do?

Tags: c++

I saw following code on c++ reference:
`bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int&rhs) const`
What does the last const do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Const Correctness](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html) tutorial:

> If you have a const object, you don't want to call methods that can
>   change the object, so you need a way of letting the compiler know
>   which methods can be safely called. These methods are called "const
>   functions", and are the only functions that can be called on a const
>   object. Note, by the way, that only member methods make sense as const
>   methods. Remember that in C++, every method of an object receives an
>   implicit this pointer to the object; const methods effectively receive
>   a const this pointer.

It might be worthwhile (*spoiler: it is*) to read through the whole article if you're new to the concept of constness.

Comment: Herb Sutter's GotW articles are quite good, too.  See [GotW #6](http://gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm).

Answer (score 1):

It means the function (operator) does not change the object.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively makes the "this" pointer a pointer to a const object. It means that members of the object cannot be modified in that method, nor can that method be invoked on a non-const object.